# Random Int Function Generating Application Force Close

Tags: android

I am having difficulty finding out why the following line of code is generating a 'Force Close' in my Android Application:

```
    fact = myArray[randfact.nextInt(myArray.length)];
```

I have an arracy of interesting facts - just a Siring Array.  It's defined in a file called array.xml and it has the name `myArray`.

The actual code snippet to generate the random fact is:

```
Random randfact = new Random();
fact = myArray[randfact.nextInt(myArray.length)];
```

where `fact` is of type string and I define `myArray` as an `Array` of `Strings` PRIOR to the above two lines of code:

```
String fact;    
String[] myArray;
```

I believe the culprit is:

```
fact = myArray[randfact.nextInt(myArray.length)];
```

because when I comment out the line as such:

```
//fact = myArray[randfact.nextInt(myArray.length)];
```

my Application no longer generates a 'Force Close'. Does anyone notice anything? I can't seem to find it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you initialising your array. You need something like:

```
myArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```

Comment: Thanks - that was ALMOST the key--here is the actual code that got this working:                                              String[] res = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);

Comment: Well I did say "something like" ;)

Comment: Upvoting since the OP didn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass 0 to Random.nextInt(n) it will throw an IllegalArgumentException - which in your case happens when myArray is a zero length array.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Android log (logcat) and it will tell you what the error is. With the device/emulator connected, run ddms.bat and it will show the log, or show Logcat in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As always, you'll want to divide your command out into multiple lines.

```
Log.d("TEST","Array length: "+myArray.length)
int nexti = randfact.nextInt(myArray.length)
Log.d("TEST","Random fact index: "+nexti)
fact = myArray[nexti];
```

While the answer is probably clear that passing 0 to random.nextInt will throw an exception, you should understand how to determine the answer to these questions yourself.